# When is a plane algebraic curve closed?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, real-algebraic-geometry

When is a plane algebraic curve closed?

Is there a metric? For quadratic http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticCurveDiscriminant.html

we know the discriminant has to be below 0.

Is there such a thing for higher degrees? I'm not looking for suggestions. I'm looking for complete answers. Not proofs of existence, because I know it exists.

Do we know it and what is it?

Comment: I think you are asking for *affine plane algebraic curve defined over $\mathbb{R}$ whose $\mathbb{R}$-points are compact w.r.t. the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$*. I suggest you add `real-algebraic-geometry` tag.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "closed". If you mean that the solution set $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid f(x,y)=0\}$ for some polynomial $f$ is a closed subset of $\Bbb R^2$, then the solution set is always closed since it's the preimage of a closed set under a continuous map. If you mean compact, that will lead to a different answer entirely.

Comment: @KReiser  I mean in this sense http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClosedCurve.html

Comment: Maybe it’s nothing more than “closed” $\Leftrightarrow$ “has no real intersection with the line at infinity”. But I’m a stranger to real algebraic geometry.

Comment: @Lubin I think this should do it - if this is the case, then the real points of the curve are compact in the standard topology and are a manifold except at the finitely many singular points. Modulo a couple facts I don't quite remember from topology, this should prove that this is a closed curve.

Comment: @KReiser “has no real intersection with the line at infinity”: this is a nice way to say "it is not open" - but the line at infinity is not something concrete  remember I'm looking for a "metric" - can this be formulated based on the coefficients of the polynomial? then I can hear it - otherwise a purely theoretical proof doesnt do me any good

Comment: Well, the intersection of a degree-$n$ curve with the line at infinity is (essentially) a set of $n$ points. That is, you’re asking about a polynomial in one variable. For quartics, I suppose you can look at the discriminant, but I don’t know whether its positivity is equivalent to there being no real points. Even worse for sextics. Of course any odd-degree curve will extend out to infinity…

Comment: @gpasch again, that's not what open means. Anyways, no real intersection with the line at infinity is concrete - it says that when the highest-degree portion of your polynomial is considered as a function on $\Bbb P^1(\Bbb R)$, this function is never zero. That's certainly concrete, and recovers the criteria you discuss in your post on quadratic functions.